# Understanding reducers and combineReducer in redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, state, reduce

So i am working with redux and i wrote a reducer to manage todos;

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import { ADD_TODO, COMPELETE_TODO, REMOVE_TODO } from "./actiontypes";

const initialState = {
    todos: [],
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TODO:
            return {
                ...state,
                todos: [...state.todos, action.payload],
            };
        case COMPELETE_TODO:
        case REMOVE_TODO:
            return {
                ...state,
                todos: state.todos.filter(
                    (todo) => state.todos.indexOf(todo) != action.payload
                ),
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default combineReducers({
    rootReducer,
});
```

As you can see that I created a reducer and user `combineReducer` and then passed it to store in other file and it is working fine.

Now how much I understood combineReducer is that it combines seperated reducers when we write them seperately. So if i change the above reducer (as i have only single reducer) to following;

```
import { ADD_TODO, COMPELETE_TODO, REMOVE_TODO } from "./actiontypes";

const initialState = {
    todos: [],
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TODO:
            return {
                ...state,
                todos: [...state.todos, action.payload],
            };
        case COMPELETE_TODO:
        case REMOVE_TODO:
            return {
                ...state,
                todos: state.todos.filter(
                    (todo) => state.todos.indexOf(todo) != action.payload
                ),
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default rootReducer;
```

And pass this to the state but it gives error. It gives undefined when i try to access `todos` by using `useSelector`;

```
const {todos} = useSelector(state => ({
    todos: state.rootReducer.todos
}))
```

So what i think is i didn't understood `combineReducers` properly. Please explain what is causing the error above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine reducer adds namespaces to the state controlled by each reducer based on the keys of the object you pass in. When you don't use combine reducer, there won't be a namespace. So change state.rootReducer to state.

Comment: Thank u both @windowsill and Rene Link . Now i got it properly. A bit of misunderstanding from my side, now cleared. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

`combineReducers` creates a reducer that separates the state of the combined reducers. In the [documentation](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) they show this example:

```
rootReducer = combineReducers({potato: potatoReducer, tomato: tomatoReducer})
```

which would produce the following state object

```
{
  potato: {
    // ... potatoes, and other state managed by the potatoReducer ...
  },
  tomato: {
    // ... tomatoes, and other state managed by the tomatoReducer, maybe some nice sauce? ...
  }
}
```

Thus when you write

```
combineReducers({
    rootReducer,
});
```

The state object will be

```
{
    rootReducer: {
       // rootReducer's state
    }
}
```

In your second example you just return the `rootReducer`. Therefore there are no separate states. The `rootReducer` operates on the root state. Thus you must adjust the selection.

```
const {todos} = useSelector(state => ({
    todos: state.todos
}))
```

Comment: I think const todos= useSelector((state) => state.potato.STATEMANAGED);